# Accept Concurrent OR Parallel request in PHP

Tags: php, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm currently working on Web Service which typically should handle 100 request at 1 minute and process all requests parallel. As per I know, the $_GET method only accept one request at a time and process it even if the client send multiple request at same instance of time. Until first request does not complete other request can not be executed.

For Example.. If suppose Client send the 10 request to the Web Service in one instance of time and consider that each request will take 10 secs to execute that means 10 requests will take 100 seconds to execute.

My question is; Can't we reduce the response time. I mean, If i execute all 10 request in parallel that means all request will execute within 10 Secs. I know this type of thing can be achieved in Java. Since I never created the web service in PHP. So please can anyone tell me how to achieve this in PHP.

Is there way to handle the requests concurrently or parallel in PHP. I searched many things regarding this on internet but unfortunately I didn't find appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying on my post.. The number of concurrent will be changed once the web service is successfully serves the 100 request per minute.. My first target is to handle 100 request.. If this works fine then my next target will be 1000 per minute..

Although I tried to install pthread on my hosting space(On Godaddy) using pcntl. But unfortunately that installation failed..Also, I did not find proper documentation of PThread. Is it possible to install PThread on my local wamp?? If yes could share the the steps with me..If I successfully install PThread on local wamp then i can set my local ip over the internet so that web service can be accessed over the internet..